# Why are Tor Browser's tor and standalone tor isolated?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, network-configuration, socks, torsocks

I have Tor Browser Bundle 6.0.7 installed on linux and I also installed stand-alone tor through `yum`. I run standalone tor in a shell while TBB is running but any shell traffic (e.g. `wget`) redirected to `torsocks` doesn't go to TBB's tor, but to standalone tor (i.e. the traffic dosen't mix), meaning `torsocks wget` won't work even if TBB is running, without standalone tor.
My process list is as follows (I simplified it):

```
    gnome-terminal-server
      bash
        sudo
          tor
      bash
        wget <-- with torsocks

    ...

    firefox
      tor
```

Why can't I redirect all traffic to one `tor`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tor Browser ships it's own copy with tor because it's intended to work without the user having to install any extra packages on a standard desktop environment. As such it comes with it's own copy of Tor which is launched by Tor Browser.

You can use `torsocks` through Tor Browser's tor or Tor Browser through the tor system daemon, it just requires configuration.

`torsocks` can be configured through `torsocks.conf`, from the `torsocks.conf(5)` manual page that explains how to configure `torsocks.conf` which is mentioned on the `torsocks(1)` manual page that explains how to use `torsocks`:

```
CONFIGURATION
SYNTAX
   The basic structure of all lines in the configuration file is:

          <directive> <parameters>

   Empty  lines  are ignored and all input on a line after a '#' character
   is ignored.

DIRECTIVES
   The following directives are used in the torsocks configuration file:
...
   TorPort port
          The port on  which  the  Tor  SOCKS  server  receives  requests.
          (default: 9050)
```

Tor Browser's Tor runs by default on port 9150, to avoid conflicting with the default system tor daemon port of 9050, by reading the manual and configuring it you can infact just use one `tor`

Comment: Wow, I never realized the two tors run on different ports. Thanks.